# How to set z-index for background-color?

Tags: html, css

I try to code a website  like "http://us-123photo.simplesite.com/". But I can not create this div. I try to use z-index for background-color, but it not work.

```css
body{
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg);
  color: white;
}
.right-side {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
.right-side .black-background{
  background-color : black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="right-side">
  <div class="black-background">
    <h3>Share</h3>
    </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my goal:
[image]

Comment: Please could you explain a bit more what effect you are trying to achieve and what effect you have achieved. Which div? Why does it need a z-index etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rgba()` on the background

```css
body{
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg);
  color: white;
}
.right-side {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.2);

}
.right-side .black-background{
  background-color : black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="right-side">
  <div class="black-background">
    <h3>Share</h3>
    </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg);
  color: white;
}
.right-side {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
}
.right-side .black-background{
  background-color : black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="right-side">
  <div class="black-background">
    <h3>Share</h3>
    </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```